# How do I disable recommended section on Windows 11 start menu

Tags: windows, start-menu, windows-11

I want to remove recent files **in the start menu** :

[image]

I don't want to use the **recommended** section in the start menu in Windows 11. Is there a way to remove it? I tried changing a setting but that also removes this section:

[image]

Comment: Mmmmm, I thought I'd search through the registry for entries in that list, then maybe write a script that deletes that registry key, but I can't find the entries in there. Maybe installing a tool that monitors registry changes and then following Andy's suggestion could point to something?

Comment: This keeps nagging me ;-) I found that many but not all entries are .lnk files in c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\, sorted by datetime. Also, there is a delay for those entries to appear; I often have to open the start menu a second time before I see them appear.

Comment: @JanDoggen Leave it, it's ok. I don't think Windows has a way to do something like this

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings > Personalization > Start > Toggle off "Show recently added apps" & "Show recently opened items in Start, Jump Lists, and File Explorer"

Comment: But that also disabled the jumplists which I want to use